# Terraria (launched with Steam) runs slowly under Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, on decent hardware

Tags: drivers, nvidia, games

Whenever I play Terraria through Steam on my laptop (T480 with MX150), Terraria slows down alot, even though Steam Overlay still reports a solid 60fps on any graphics settings, although the game's obviously not ever hitting a solid 60fps. Movement gets jittery, although my cpu usage isn't really getting that high (about 50-60%, according to Conky). I have the proper Nvidia drivers installed, and i've reinstalled the drivers.

With the same game, launched under Steam on Windows 10 (dual-boot), it runs perfectly fine even without Nvidia drivers, as expected. Because of that, I'd assume it's something wrong with Ubuntu, maybe driver issues, but I have no clue past that.

I do also notice that I idle at 20% CPU usually, and about 3-4GiB of RAM after i've had the computer sitting around for a bit (usually about 800-900 MiB right at startup). I don't know if that would be inportant information.

Comment: Of note: In Windows you're **always** with Nvidia drivers, either the version already incorporated (usually an older version) or the user installed executable downloaded from Nvidia (usually the most up-to-date version). There's no Windows alternative driver equivalent to the `nouveau` which is the default in Ubuntu. Now, which driver version have your installed in Ubuntu? For MX150, at the time of this writting it should be 430.